# Why does json_decode convert my unicode string?

Tags: php, json, unicode

I have a string with Unicode characters.

For example:

```
$s = '"x9gtjw\u001d91ffd0\u001d92K"';
var_dump($s, json_decode($s));
```

This gives the ouput:

```
string '"x9gtjw\u001d91ffd0\u001d92K"' (length=29)
string 'x9gtjw91ffd092K' (length=17)
```

Why does json_decode convert my unicode symbols?

I am using PHP 7.2.

I tried to use flags(like `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE`) but they didn't help.

Update:

I need use `json_decode` without converting `\uXXXX` to  the hex `\xXX`.

For example:

```
$s = '{"code":"zz\u001d"}';
$json = json_decode($s);
if($json->code == 'zz\u001d') {...}
```

String `$s` contains non-visible characters `\x1d`.

I tried converting the backslashes into double backslashes - which had no effect on the output.

Comment: Why do you say Unicode symbols? Care to elaborate on source, context and why you expected something different?

Comment: Where does `$s` come from? Basically you need to turn those backslashes into double backslashes before `json_decode()`'ing.

Comment: The U+001D control characters aren't visible here, but they seem to be present in the decoded string, as you would get length=15 otherwise. What did you expect the function to return instead?

Comment: i take json from API by curl. then i do json_decode and have converted strings. i tryed convert string  jw\\u001d9 and got the same result.

Comment: lenz, you right i have <0x1d> symbols in string. i expect string with \uXXXX characters. i need   json_decode({"code": "zz\u001d"}) -> $s->code == 'zz\u001d'

Comment: You should update your question with all this information, so people who know the answer don't have two piece things together from the comments. Also, if you add "@" before the user names, people will get notified when you mention them in comments.

Comment: If the JSON string contains `\u....`, then those are Unicode escape sequences and they will be decoded by any JSON decoder into characters (which are invisible in this case). It’s unclear why you’d expect something else.

Comment: Just one note on wording: If you `json_decode()` a string, then the result is some data structure or primitive PHP type. Calling the result `$json` is misleading. You `$s` is JSON, your `$json` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The characters still exist in the decoded string`string 'x9gtjw91ffd092K' (length=17)`, but they are not being displayed.  1D is the ASCII control code for group separator(a non-printable character).

Note the size of the string length is two larger(17) than the string as displayed(15), since the UTF-8 character is `\x1d` and there are two in the string.

If the character were: `\u0A1`(Upsidedown Exclamation Point) the UTF-8 version would add 2 extra bytes(`\xc2\xa1`). This can exist for up to 4 extra bytes (Higher UTF-32 Emojis).

Your comparison is not working because:

You must double the double backslash `\\\\` to escape the Unicode encoding.

```
$s = '{"code":"zz\\\\u001d"}';
$json = json_decode($s);
if($json->code == 'zz\u001d') {...}
```

otherwise the `\u001d` will be interpreted on decode.

The more natural way of doing it is explained here (not what was asked, but still as solution):

PHP requires double quotes <kbd>"</kbd> when it contains the `\uXXXX` escape sequences. [Reference("Double quoted" section, 1 page down )](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Simply change your detection code follow that requirement:

```
$s = '{"code":"zz\u001d"}';
$json = json_decode($s);
if($json->code == "zz\u001d") {...}
```

The code given in `{...}` will now run.

Comment: Strom, you implicitly asked why I wrote a different answer when yours already answers the issue. Point is, that the wording you use is not precise enough and rather misleading. You write "...in the string", but fail to specify which one. Also, "characters of "\x1d"" are nowhere. You have a byte/character with the value 0x1d in the result of `json_decode()` but not multiple "characters". It's these small details like the distinctions between source code, JSON-encoded strings and data structures that result from decoding the former that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings `$s` (both of them!) don't contain any "non-visible characters \x1d" (group separator (GS) according to ASCII). They both contain a literal backslash followed by the letter "u" etc.

Now, what else is wrong there: If you print the string `'a\x0ab'`, you will get it just as it stands here, minus the quotes. If you print the string `"a\x0ax"`, you will get an "a" and a "b" separated by a linebreak. String literals with single quotes behave differently from those with double quotes in PHP.

Now, you may be wondering how to avoid json_decode() from interpreting the `\uxxxx` sequence. Simple answer is: You can't, because that would be against the JSON specification and no sane parser would ever do that. What you can do is basically two things:

1. Fix the input to contain a backslash that is not part of an escape sequence. That means, you must double the backslash in the input string. Since in PHP, a backslash is interpreted as escape symbol as well, you will have to quadruple it. You can see that if you encode the expected outcome using `json_encode()`.
2. Fix whatever you want to do with the output. Ask yourself why you want something in the output string that is not intended to be represented by the JSON, like control characters, which are explicitly excluded. If it's just because you can't display it or because it messes with some formatting, then make sure when outputting it that things work, but don't change the internal representation to something counterintuitive.

Comment: Are you stating with #2, that raw Unicode values were "not intended to be represented by the JSON".  Could you provide a reference to that fact? It is my understanding that the intention of JSON is: to provide [universal data structures](https://www.json.org/).  It is my understanding that JSON has no limitations on the datatypes it encodes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, @Strom. I tried to clarify what I wrote a bit further. Concerning the limitations on datatypes, JSON only encodes a subset of all possible PHP strings. In particular non-textual (often called "binary") data is not valid. Further, control sequences are explicitly excluded. Concerning my "discrediting the OP's assumptions", I'd rather consider these misconceptions, which are worth shattering along with the conclusions built on them. The educator in me believes this is important.